# tensorflow image recognition api

Tags: api, tensorflow, image-recognition, bazel

I am trying to run a Tensorflow API for image recognition. I followed this tutorial on tensor flow

https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/tutorials/image_recognition/index.html#image-recognition

I want to use this for an android application and for that, tensorflow directed me to a github link which required me to install bazel.

i followed all the installation steps listed at
https://www.bazel.io/versions/master/docs/install.html#ubuntu

But i am getting this error

ERROR: /DEFAULT.WORKSPACE:63:1: in bind rule //external:android/sdk: The external label '//external:android/sdk' is not bound to anything.

ERROR: Analysis of target '//tensorflow/examples/android:tensorflow_demo' failed; build aborted.

I am unable to understand what is wrong. Can someone help me in this?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you did not run `./configure`, or that it did not succeed.

For installation and build issues, we do answer questions on our github page: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues

where you can submit a full report including your configuration.